# `read_sql_query` to pandas Timezone being interpreted incorrectly

Tags: sql, pandas, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy

I am using a package called [aws data wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler) to read a MYSQL table from Glue Catalog to Pandas dataframe.

The steps are simple. First create a `sql_engine` and a sql statement, then execute the sql statement by `wr.db.read_sql_query(query, con=sql_engine)`

The resulting dataframe is

```
transaction_date                 created_on                modified_on
0     2017-10-04 00:00:00 2018-10-05 10:56:39.000000 2018-10-05 10:56:39.000000
1     2017-10-04 00:00:00 2018-10-05 10:56:39.000000 2018-10-05 10:56:39.000000
2     2017-10-04 00:00:00 2018-10-05 10:56:39.000000 2018-10-05 10:56:39.000000
3     2017-10-04 00:00:00 2018-10-05 10:56:39.000000 2018-10-05 10:56:39.000000
4     2017-10-04 00:00:00 2018-10-05 10:56:39.000000 2018-10-05 10:56:39.000000
...                   ...                        ...                        ...
33901 2020-11-05 06:20:25 2020-11-06 06:20:34.100835 2020-11-06 06:20:34.100877
33902 2020-11-05 06:20:34 2020-11-06 06:20:43.551528 2020-11-06 06:20:43.551551
33903 2020-11-05 06:34:58 2020-11-06 06:35:34.719571 2020-11-06 06:35:34.719592
33904 2020-11-05 06:35:34 2020-11-06 06:35:45.229119 2020-11-06 06:35:45.229141
33905 2020-11-05 06:35:45 2020-11-06 06:36:03.171246 2020-11-06 06:36:03.171269
```

while the datetime in the database is

```
transaction_date                 created_on                modified_on
2017-10-04 08:00:00 2018-10-05 18:56:39 2018-10-05 18:56:39
2017-10-04 08:00:00 2018-10-05 18:56:39 2018-10-05 18:56:39
2017-10-04 08:00:00 2018-10-05 18:56:39 2018-10-05 18:56:39
2017-10-04 08:00:00 2018-10-05 18:56:39 2018-10-05 18:56:39
```

I am living in Hong Kong. The datetime in the dataframe seems being subtracted by 8 hours.

I have also asked the question in [Github](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/issues/444). The developer suggested that I specifiy the Timezone at the session level, for example,

```
sql_engine = wr.catalog.get_engine(connection,
    connect_args={
        "init_command": "SET SESSION time_zone='+00:00'"
    })
```

But, it seems that changing the session timezone does not change anything. That means even I change the timezone to UTC or UTC+8, the resulting dataframe is the same.